# Function takes reals exactly twice

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function f : R → R that takes every real value exactly twice?

What is the meaning of taking  value exactly twice?

Comment: It means $f(x)=k$ has two solutions for every $k$.

Comment: It means that $f(x)=k$ has *exactly* two solutions for every $k$, to be precise. The fact that it must be *exactly* two, is essential to this question.

Comment: It is quite intuitive that there cannot exist such functions, as, intuitively speaking, they would have to go to $-\infty$ twice and $\infty$ twice, and continuous functions can only go to them once, or one of them twice.

Comment: Apologies for hurried question reading. It means $f(x)=k$ has two solutions for every $k$ as @DHMOmentioned.